# Как посчитать сумму количества значений столбцов до заданного в функции?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, процедуры

Имеются несколько столбцов, названные от 1 до 12, в них содержатся различные значения, они не важны, важно их количество.

Пример:

```
1  2  3  4  ...(столбцы)
*  *     *  
   *  *  *   (значения)
*     *  *
```

Пишу процедуру, которая должна считать сумму количества значений столбцов до заданного. Т.е., приняв входным параметром значение, например, 3, процедура должна рассчитать сумму количества значений в столбцах до третьего включительно.

```
1  2  3
2+ 2+ 2  = 6
```

Логично, что должен использоваться `loop`, однако ввиду слабых познаний в PL/SQL и в программировании в целом, застопорился практически в самом начале.

Как реализовать цикл для выполнения данной операции?

Comment: Вам не обязательно делать цикл. Сделайте подсчет числа значений по каждому столбцу `COUNT (1), COUNT(2) ...` и складывайте их значения.

Comment: @vikolyada Спасибо за подсказку! Но тем не менее - знать сумму нужно до определенного, а не всех. Как это можно красиво описать?

Comment: Например, можно сделать `CASE 'входной параметр с числом столбцов' WHEN 1 THEN COUNT(1) WHEN 2 THEN COUNT(1) + COUNT(2) ... END`. Может не самый оптимальный вариант, но по идее должно работать.

Comment: @vikolyada, CASE WHEN 'входной параметр с числом столбцов' >= 1 THEN COUNT(1) ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN 'входной параметр с числом столбцов' >= 2 THEN COUNT(2) ELSE 0 END + ...

Comment: @ГерманБорисов а зачем делать 12 `CASE` когда достаточно одного?

Comment: @vikolyada, чтобы было 12 `COUNT`'ов, а не 72

Comment: @ГерманБорисов разницы никакой, что 12, что 72 `COUNT`. Оптимизатор не будет повторно производить подсчет.

Comment: Можно использовать UNPIVOT

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
with function countVal (n int, empty char:=' ') return number is
    ret int;
begin
    select count (trim (empty from val)) into ret 
    from t unpivot (val for col in (c1, c2, c3, c4))
    where col <= 'C'||n;
    return ret;
end;
select countVal (3) n3 from dual  
/

        N3
----------
         6
```

---

Данные для примера:

```
create table t as
with t (c1, c2, c3, c4) as (
    select '*', '*', ' ', '*' from dual union all
    select ' ', '*', '*', '*' from dual union all
    select '*', ' ', '*', '*' from dual) select * from t
/
```

Answer (score 0):

ничего не понял, поясните на примере:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_data ( 
  c1 NUMBER, 
  c2 NUMBER,
  c3 NUMBER,
  c4 NUMBER,
  c5 NUMBER,
  c6 NUMBER,
  c7 NUMBER,
  c8 NUMBER,
  c9 NUMBER,
  c10 NUMBER,
  c11 NUMBER,
  c12 NUMBER
);
/
INSERT INTO tmp_data (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10,
            c11, c12) VALUES ( 1, 1, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL ); 
/
INSERT INTO tmp_data (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10,
            c11, c12) VALUES ( NULL, 1, 1, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL ); 
/
INSERT INTO tmp_data (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10,
            c11, c12) VALUES ( 1, NULL, 1, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );   
/                    

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_COUNT_RS(
  A_START  IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
  A_END IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
 TYPE l_col_sum_typ IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   l_c_sum  l_col_sum_typ ;

   l_end NUMBER := A_END;
   l_result NUMBER :=0;

BEGIN

  SELECT  COUNT(t.c1),
          COUNT(t.c2),
          COUNT(t.c3),
          COUNT(t.c4),
          COUNT(t.c5),
          COUNT(t.c6),
          COUNT(t.c7),
          COUNT(t.c8),
          COUNT(t.c9),
         COUNT(t.c10),
         COUNT(t.c11),
         COUNT(t.c12) 
         INTO l_c_sum(1), l_c_sum(2), l_c_sum(3), 
              l_c_sum(4), l_c_sum(5), l_c_sum(6), 
              l_c_sum(7), l_c_sum(8), l_c_sum(9), 
              l_c_sum(10), l_c_sum(11), l_c_sum(12)
    FROM tmp_data t;


   IF l_end IS NULL OR l_end > l_c_sum.count THEN
      l_end := l_c_sum.count;
   END IF;
   FOR idx IN A_START..l_end LOOP
      l_result := l_result+l_c_sum(idx);
      dbms_output.put_line(idx|| l_c_sum(idx));
   END LOOP;
  RETURN l_result;
END F_COUNT_RS;
/

SELECT F_COUNT_RS(1,3) FROM dual;
```

Comment: Может проще тогда через динамический SQL сделать чем так хардкорить? )))